# Frequency of Math Symbols

Tags: statistics, notation

Does anyone know of a study that has calculated the frequency of math symbols based on some popular mathematics journals or math corpus?

For example in English you have letter frequencies of the most common english documents.

[image]

Obviously the list is much larger in Mathematics, but it would be interesting to see what characters are used the most in mathematics.  (This question might be better fit for meta.math.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com or even mathematica.stackexchange.com)

**Question:** Does anyone know of a frequency table that plots out the frequency of math symbols based on mathematic journals or a math corpus?

Comment: I don't think that this is on topic here, so I'm voting to close. Perhaps you would be better served at the statistical analysis stack exchange? Also, just so you know, meta sites are for questions about the main sites themselves, not about "meta-mathematics" for example. Best of luck!

Comment: @TomOldfield Stats transferred it back here, so please nobody else vote to close the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382730/frequency-of-math-symbols

Comment: What do you think could be done with such an analysis?  Letter and word frequency analyses have uses in cryptography, but I don't see such a use for an analysis of mathematical symbols.  And do you intend to differentiate between the use of a symbol for different meanings (e.g. "<" for "ordered by" and "<" as "is a subgroup of"?

Comment: @postmortes well for input on computers you could display the most used ones at the top of the list.

Comment: @William - that seems like a good use, though I think you might still fall foul of the context issue.
And please accept my apologies; I hadn't noticed how old this question was until after I'd added a comment!

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it seems that no one has good answer. Maybe no one has made an analysis. It should be possible though , by hand or by computer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so for the specific symbols.  It would vary so widely from topic to topic that it would be a bit pointless.

Nate Eldrige at Cornell did a fair amount of frequency analysis on words and phrases that come up in maths papers in order to come up with [this](http://thatsmathematics.com/blog/archives/102) delightful ruse.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics isn't a language in itself. It's a huge collection of languages and dialects with many, many symbols.

It's unclear what one can gleam from such an analysis. Languages tend to follow Zipf's Law or other power law distributions. However mathematics is much less homogenous. The frequency of vowels in scientific journals vs Shakespeare poetry is going to be pretty similar but the differences in symbols for a differential geometry paper vs a numerical linear algebra paper will be wholly different. Not to mention it's extremely ambiguous to speak of math symbols. I suppose you could look up Latex code for each math symbol and count stuff that way. Or you could restrict your attention to a select few. But then you'll run into the homogeneity issue.

Comment: You are right there are some ambiguity issues with the question, but using either latex characters or unicode code values, I believe some could get an approximate understanding of the frequency of different symbols, characters, alphabet characters, etc..