# Frequency of Math Symbols

Tags: statistics, notation

Does anyone know of a study that has calculated the frequency of math symbols based on some popular mathematics journals or math corpus?

For example in English you have letter frequencies of the most common english documents.

[image]

Obviously the list is much larger in Mathematics, but it would be interesting to see what characters are used the most in mathematics.  (This question might be better fit for math.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com or even mathematica.stackexchange.com)

**Question:** Does anyone know of a frequency table the plots out the frequency of math symbols based on mathematic journals or a math corpus?

Comment: @amWhy, same post, same OP. Fishy...

Comment: Would need to define "the same math symbol". The very same can mean very, very different things depending on context. Then there are several competing notations. Add accents and other decorations...  Get a large set of LaTeX texts written with the same packages, and analyze the usage of macros.

Comment: @vonbrand He was told on the first to ask on stats, and they just sent him back here.

Comment: @vonbrand I was told to post to stats.  Posted it there and got transferred back here.  It's no problem assuming the other isn't closed also.

Comment: This question is very hard to answer, for the reasons I explain in the comment. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @vonbrand Ideally variables would be separated by context, but at this point a study showing the frequency of characters ignoring there context would work fine.